# Placement for jQuery plugin within a custom jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've got a small plugin that is based off [this boilerplate](http://%20https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.basic.plugin-boilerplate.js).

Everything is working fine, but was wanting to focus on the placement of one of the small, sort of "helper", functions within the plugin. Here is the snippet.

```js
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
 
    var pluginName = 'test',
  defaults = {};
 
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function() {
            $(this.element).find(':input').each(function() {
    $(this).setValue('value');
   });
        }
    };
 
 $.fn.setValue = function(value) {
  var $el = $(this);
  if ($el.prop('type') == 'checkbox') {
   $el.prop('checked', true);
  } else {
   $el.val(value);
  }
 };
 
    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);

$('#apply-test').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $('#test').test();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <form id="test">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" name="notifications" id="notifications" class="form-check-input">
                <label for="notifications" class="form-check-label">
                    Receive Notifications
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="apply-test" class="btn btn-primary">Apply Test</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Within the plugin you'll notice another function like so:

```
$.fn.setValue = function(value) {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.prop('type') == 'checkbox') {
        $el.prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $el.val(value);
    }
};
```

Now I can place that code anywhere I like inside or outside of that plugin and it works just fine. Also, the reason I'm using a function like this is so that I can make easy use of it when setting form element values in a way that is pretty much the same as using the standard `$(el).val()`.

My questions are as follows:

- Is there maybe some way to set it up so that the function is private?
- And if not, is placing it right inside the function like it is in the
  fiddle an OK way to go about adding little helper functions like
  this?
- Or is there some other approach that would be recommended?
- Or maybe helpers like these should just be their own stand alone
  plugins? (probably just a preference thing here)

Comment: Is this assertion correct ? «_You need the function `setValue` to be only accessible from within your plugin._»

Comment: Well I don't need it to be I was just wondering if there was a way to do so. Just trying to learn you know..

Comment: The function is only meant to be used within the plugin itself for it's functionality.

Comment: So my advice is: you'd better stick to what my answer suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that once `$.fn.setValue = function …` is executed, *setValue* function can be called from anywhere in your application (with something like `$('randomSelector').setValue()`) and that's probably not your intent.

To make the `setValue` function only accessible from within your plugin, you could make its behavior dependent on supplied arguments:

```
(function ($, window, document) {
    // …
// Make setValue only accessible through the plugin
    function setValue = function(value) {
      if (this.prop('type') == 'checkbox') {
        this.prop('checked', true);
      } else {
        this.val(value);
      }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options, more) {
// Test arguments and call setValue when appropriate
      if (options === 'set') {
        // Apply setValue on the current jquery Collection
        setValue.apply(this, more);
        // Make your plugin "chainable"
        return this;

      // Eventually handle other scenarios
      } else /* if (…) */ { ; }

      // Your default plugin behavior
      return this.each(function() {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
          $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName,
            new Plugin(this, options));
        }
      });
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Then you call your plugin this way:

```
$('#apply-test').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Call setValue
  $('#test').test('set', 1);
  // Standard call
  $('#test').test();
});
```

Side note: within plugin functions `$.fn.xxx = function() {/*here*/}`, `this` points to the jquery collection that triggered the plugin function call. So `var $el = $(this);` in such context is useless (it only add overhead), simply use `this` or eventually either `this.eq(0)` or `this.each(…)`.

Comment: Ah thank you for that tip about `this` within `$.fn.xxx`! I hadn't really noticed that before.. But there's no harm really in leaving the function right where it is now up in the example is there? I've been looking around at other plugins to see if any of them sorta do the same thing but I haven't really found any yet so that's why I ask.. Thanks!

Comment: @Rick The problem with `$.fn.setValue = function …` is that setValue can be called with `$('randomSelector').setValue()` anywhere at anytime in your application and that might not be your intent. Only "whole" plugin should be put into `$.fn` namespace. Helper functions on the other hand should be enclosed in the appropriate namespace. Rule of thumb: The less contexts depend on a particular helper function, the more it has to be "privatized".

Comment: @Rick Consider marking your question as answered/solved by ticking the answer.

Comment: Well it really hasn't answered my question but I guess it got me to the answer of it cannot be done and I appreciate  the tip about `this` within `$.fn.xxx` so I'll accept.

Comment: My answer tells that your code effectively doesn't make setValue private (relative to the plugin definition) because making it a property of  `$.fn` also makes the function callable from almost anywhere. To make it private and avoid misuses , simply define it like I did in my snippet.

Comment: Right but then you called it in the onclick outside of the plugin like so `$('#test').test('set', 1);` rather than within the plugin itself.. So I'm pretty sure the entire `if (options === 'set') {` part is unnecessary. Anyways, I ended up just adding another method after the init function `value: function($el, value) {` and called that privately `plugin.value($(this), 'value')`. I appreciate your input!

Comment: I thought you wanted it accessible only via your plugin ^^ which would prevent the developer from using the helper function without knowing setValue is part of it. So, in the end,   if this is not what you intended,  simply remove the if part as you say. Your new implementation will do the job!